# Performing operation on Select statement result

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am creating a stored procedure which takes following parameters:

```
 @LessonId char(15), @TeacherName char(25), @TeacherSessionId char(10),
 @CurrentTeacher char(25) OUTPUT
```

This is what I want to do:

1. Inserts a new row if the LessonId doesn't exist in the table
2. If it already exists it needs to do the following:
   a) check if the TeacherName & TeacherSessionId are the same as mine ( input parameters), if yes just update the LoginTime
   b) if the TeacherName OR TeacherSessionId in database are not the same as mine, this lesson belongs to someone else so return the teacher's name

What is the best way to avoid running too many SELECT operations on the table.
I know that I can do something like this:

```
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Lessontb WHERE LessonId = @LessonId )
  BEGIN
      INSERT...
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
      IF EXISTS (SELECT TeacherName FROM Lessontb 
                 WHERE TeacherName <> @TeacherName 
                    OR TeacherSessionId <> @TeacherSessionId )
      BEGIN
          SET @CurrentTeacher = TeacherName
      END

      IF EXISTS (SELECT TeacherName FROM Lessontb  
                 WHERE TeacherName = @TeacherName 
                   AND TeacherSessionId = @TeacherSessionId )
      BEGIN  
         UPDATE ... LoginTime
      END
    END
```

I am quite sure there must be a more clean way to do this, for instance running the 2nd and 3rd steps on the result set of the first SELECT but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

Potential problem. It appears that you are using LessionID as the key column. But later down the code, you ignore the key column.

Potential solution: Do one select and load them into variables, also save the clustered key column into the variable as well. Work out your logic and then issue one update. If you update with the clustered key, the overhead would be very less.

Naz